# In Github how can I view a commit showing just which files were changed?

Tags: github

In Github if I list the commits for a repo, and then click on the SHA to view one of the commits, instead of just listing which files were changed in that commit it instead displays the diff of the entire commit, which might be the combined changes of dozens of files all displayed inline on a hundred page long webpage.

This is completley useless to me. When I view a commit in the first instance I just want to see which files have been changed. If I want to then drill down further to see the diff of a particular file I will do so.

How in Github can I see just the names of which files have been changed in a commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, click on the "N changed files" link in the commit page. An example taken from [this repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap):

[image]

This expands a list of all files modified in the commit, including new files added (green), existing files modified (yellow), and files deleted (red).